# Why do determinants in this specific case can be removed?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Good evening everyone,

Why do determinants on both sides in the case below can be removed? And what do we actually do in order to achieve it? Thank you.

$\det(S^{-1})\det(\lambda$**I**$ - A)\det(S) = \det(\lambda$**I**$ - A)$

[image]

Comment: It depends on your country. In mine you could get a 5 year sentence!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Which crime can you be charged with for illegally removing determinants?  Destruction of public properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any invertible matrix $S$, $\det(S^{-1}) = \det(S)^{-1}$, so the $\det(S^{-1})$ and $\det(S)$ cancel.

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting. Where can I read more about extracting the power? It is not obvious to me that we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any square matrix $M$, $\det(M)$ is always a real number, hence

$\det(S^{-1})\det(\lambda I-A)\det(S)=\det(S^{-1})\det(S)\det(\lambda I-A)$

by commutativity of real number multiplication. Now since $\det(S^{-1})=(\det(S))^{-1}$, or in otherwords, $\det(S^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(S)}$, it follows that

$\det(S^{-1})\det(S)\det(\lambda I-A)=\det(\lambda I-A)$.

Comment: Well, not for _every_ matrix the determinant is a _real_ number.

Comment: I took it as an assumption that the entries of the matrices were real numbers. Indeed matrices whose entries come from another field, such as $\mathbb{C}$ can be non-real, but they will come from whichever field the entries of the matrices came from.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that det() is a number actually.